# Несколько связаных EditText android

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу реализовать ввод 4х значного пин-кода. Для каждой цифры я сделал отдельный EditText. Соответственно в один EditText можно записать только один символ. Мне нужно что бы при вводе символа фокус автоматически перемещался на следующий EditText, аналогично для удаления. Я попробовал реализовать это с помощью TextWatcher:

```
inner class EnterCodeTextWatcher(private var prevFocus: EditText?, private var nextFocus: EditText?) : TextWatcher {

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (s.isNullOrEmpty() && prevFocus != null){
            prevFocus?.requestFocus()
            prevFocus?.isCursorVisible = true
        }
        else if (!s.isNullOrEmpty() && nextFocus != null){
            nextFocus?.requestFocus()
            nextFocus?.isCursorVisible = true
        }
    }

}
```

Это хорошо работает если вводить все 4 символа и удалять все 4 символа. Но если ввести только 2 символа и попытаться удалить один символ, то ничего не получится, потому что фокус будет на следующем EditText, который является пустым. Как решить эту проблему? Или может нужно делать это другим способом?

Comment: лучше всего воспользоваться готовой библиотекой, их [довольно много](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+pin+code&type=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может это вам поможет

```
   setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (getText().length() == 0 && previousView != null) {
                    previousView.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Это помогло. Но я заметил что на эмуляторе не вызывается эта функция при нажатии на экранную кнопку удалить. Если нажимать на клавиатуре то работает, так же работает на моем устройстве с прошивкой MIUI. Вы не знаете с чем это может быть связано?